# Restoring SBS 2011 Domain Controller with no DSRM logon access

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backup, backup-restoration, restore, windows-sbs-2011

I have a client's server running SBS 2011, it is their only server.

I need to restore their OS to a previous date. Everything can go back to that date last week.

They have a Windows Image Backup.

When I try to log on in DSRM i get 'Logon servers no available' for the domain admin account, I get username or password incorrect when I try to log on as the DSRM admin .\administrator

The password is not an issue, I have successfully reset the DSRM password using ndtsutil.

Is there some trick that I'm missing?

Is there any way of restoring from the bare metal backup of the Windows Image Backup possibly using another application to just overwrite everything and ignore all this?

This is only a 20 user environment, no changes have been made to active directory in Months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this process would work for you to restore your backups: http://www.wbadmin.info/articles/howto-bare-metal-restores-windows-server-2008-backup.html - SBS 2011 is just a repackaged Windows Server 2008 R2.

I would recommend restoring onto a different hard disk so you can extract data from the original disk if it should be neccessary.

Comment: Thanks!, We had already copied the vital data off such as exchange. We ended up using Acronis Recovery to restore from the Windows Image Backup